# the keyword "final" for BigDecimal.java

Tags: java, keyword, final, bigdecimal

as everyone knows, the  immutable class in java should be modified by the keyword "final". But, why the class BigDecimal.java is an Exception?

Comment: `immutable != final` - `immutable` means that the value of an instance can't be changed while `final` means you can't create subclasses. There are other immutable but non-final classes like `java.util.Date` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Immutable** means, that class does not contain any method that would change it's internal state.

Example of *immutable* class:

```
class ImmutableInteger {
    private final int value;

    public ImmutableInteger(int value) {this.value = value;}

    public int value() {return value;}

    public ImmutableInteger add(int a) {
        // instead of changing this state, we will create new instance with result
        return new ImmutableInteger(value + a);
    }
}
```

Example of *mutable* class:

```
class MutableInteger {
    private int value;

    public MutableInteger(int value) {this.value = value;}

    public int value() {return value;}

    public MutableInteger add(int a) {
        value += a; // mutating internal state
        return this;
    }
}
```

Modifier **final** means, that variable can not be changed. For variable of *object type* it means, that variable can not refer to other object. For variable of *primitive type* (byte, short, int, long, float, double) it means, that value can not be changed.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(1);
BigDecimal b = a.add(new BigDecimal(1)); // returns result in new instance (a is not changed = immutable)
a = new BigDecimal(5); // ok, 'a' is not final = can be change to refer to other BigDecimal instance)

final BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(1);
BigDecimal c = b.add(new BigDecimal(2)); // // returns result in new instance (a is not changed = immutable)
b = new BigDecimal(5); // NOT OK!!!, 'b' is final = can not be changed to refer to other object
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see it.

Comment: @ValueYouth if it helps, feel free to mark this answer as 'accepted' :)

Answer (score 2):

> why the class BigDecimal.java is an Exception?

is not, final keyword means that you just can't change the reference of the bigdecimal, you can still change the value of the object...

```
final BigDecimal myDec = BigDecimal.valueOf(1L);
System.out.println(myDec);
myDec = myDec.plus(); //invalid, you cant change the ref
```

the point to consider here is tha **BigDecimal** is inmutable, so all the operations that change the content of the object will return a new instance of the **BigDecimal** too....

Answer (score 2):

No. No. No.

`final` does **not** mean that you can't *modify* an object through that reference.

When applied to references, `final` means that the reference cannot be changed to refer to a different object. It is **not** equivalent to the `const` qualifier of C++.

*Immutability* means that there are no methods provided that modify an object's state.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an exception.
BigDecimal in itself is `immutable`, be cause none of this method does modify the object value. **But** you can change the variable reference.

```
BigDecimal bd = new Bigdecimal(10);
bd = bd.add(new BigDecimal(50)); // bd new equals 60
```

If you declare your BigDecimal final, you won't be able to change the reference anymore.

```
final BigDecimal bd = new Bigdecimal(10);
final total = bd.add(new BigDecimal(50)); // Total new equals 60
// bd = bd.add(new BigDecimal(50)); // Will FAIL
```